# Google Plus button displaying wrong count

Tags: google-plus

The Google+ button http://www.amayzinghomes.com is displaying the wrong count. This is a brand new domain so it should only be showing a few clicks. I think it may be displaying the number of clicks on the Google Plus page where I got the script instead of the count for the actual page it's on. Here's the script I used:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="http://www.amayzinghomes.com/"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
s</script>
```

Comment: I've got the same problem on a wp blog, some posts show a g+ counter of 26k which isn't correct, since it's the number of the g+ of the google plus page of the blog. This error happens only on some posts (it hapenns in 5 posts and the blog has near 5 thousands posts).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the count of 7 comes from links shared on Google+.

I do see one public post via this search:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/amayzinghomes

There may be private posts with that URL too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, https://plus.google.com/116401211377269068112 shows count over 180 while the JavaScript plugin shows only 13 on [www.ceriseshirts.com](http://www.ceriseshirts.com/) . The code is given below

```
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="bubble" data-width="60" data-height="69" data-href="https://plus.google.com/116401211377269068112"></div>
        <script>
        (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
        </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post new questions in the space for answers. If your situation is sufficiently different from the OP's, you can post a new question using the "Ask Question" button. Alternatively, you'll have to work on earning "reputation points". With enough points, you will be able to vote, comment, and set bounties to draw attention to questions. Good luck!